Cokernel of the ring map $k[t] \to k[x,y]$
Let $k$ be a field and $\phi : k[t] \to k[x,y]$ be a graded ring homomorphism generated by $\phi(1)=1$ and $\phi(t) = x+y$. Here $t, x, y$ having degree $1$. I am interested in finding a nice form of the cokernel of the map $\phi$.
It is easy to compute the degree-wise cokernel, though it looks messy in higher degrees.
Can anyone suggest me a nice form of the cokernel?
A geometric motivation can be thought of as follows:
Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal subgroup of the Klein $4$-group $K_4.$ We have a canonical quotient map $K_4 \to K_4/\Delta$. Then the above map is the induced map in the group cohomology.
Any help would be appreciated.

Hope that this answer is correct.
Two polynomials in $k[x,y]$ represent the same element if and only if their difference is in $k[x+y]$.
Using the relations $x=(x+y)-y$, $x^2=(x+y)^2-2xy-y^2$, $x^3=(x+y)^3-3x^2y-3xy^2-y^3$ and so on, you can eliminate from any polynomial the pure terms of the form $cx^m$ (including the costant term), so you are left with a polynomial of the form $y\cdot f(x,y)$,
so it holds $\mathrm{coker}(\phi)= y \cdot k[x,y]$.

Thank you for your quick answer. Can you say something about the $\mathrm{Char}(k)=2$ case? In particular, for $k= \mathbb{F}_2.$
